# Render solid color in Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, color

I wan't to create a segmentation map for machine learning.
For that I have a list of colors like:

```
clouds  #aaaaaa
cow     #4f445b
grass   #1dc331
```

It is from absolute importance that the render has the exact same colors.

I tried:
[image]

And:
[image]

But in the render the colors are off.
How can I get a render with the exact colors I give?

Comment: Simpliest way if you download Blender 2.79 and use the Blender Render engine. It has a shadless option for the materials. / Did you try  the emission shader only?

Comment: I don't want to jump between 2.79 and 2.8, part of why am doing this is getting into blender 2.8. Using the emission shader only has the same result.

Comment: I thought "blender render" was "workbench" in 2.8. Can you just use workbench?

Comment: Dave44 said well. I didn't know, but workbench is the same as Blender Render. Just use "Flat" for lighting in the Render properties tab.

Comment: workbench isn't the same as blender render, at least I don't think it is.  It's basically a engine used for open GL renders.  It would work well in this case.

Comment: Are you sure the colors are off?  They were the same when I tried it.

Comment: @millard Did you use eevee?

Comment: yes.  I tested it, by clicking on my rgb color in the node panel, selecting the tear drop tool, and pressing on the object in the rendered image.  the color didn't change, so I knew that it was the same.

Answer (score 4):

There are mainly four steps you should take, when following your approach with emissive materials in Eevee:

1. In the *Color Management* panel, set the *View Transform* to *Raw* (if you're not saving as OpenEXR)
2. Use the RGB slider to set the color values or be aware of gamma correction
3. Be aware of floating point inaccuracies or use OpenEXR as file format with *Float(Full)*
4. Disable anti-aliasing

The first point ensures that the exact scene referred values are stored without mapping them to different values through the view transform. The filmic view transform would be useful for realism when rendering a scene, but not for non-color data such as masks.

The second point ensures that you don't get confused with the gamma correction. By setting it through the RGB slider, you're directly entering the values used in the scene without gamma correction as explained in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/templates/color_picker.html). The output will therefore contain these exact values when using the raw view transform as long as the image format can represent them. You can use the hex values, but be aware that they are interpreted as gamma corrected. This is common practice, but I've seen people get confused by this.

> In Blender, the Hex and HSV/HSL values are automatically [gamma](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html#term-gamma)
>   corrected however, for the RGB values, they are in Scene Linear color
>   space, and are therefore not gamma corrected. For more information,
>   see the [Color Management and Exposure](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html) page.

The third point ensures that the selected color value can be accurately represented in the image format and is exactly the floating point value you chose in the color picker. If you use OpenEXR, you don't have to set the *View Transform* to *Raw* because it already stores the raw values. Of course you can choose a different image format, but it may not be able to represent the color accurately because of lower floating point precision or because it uses the [0-255] range per color channel.

The last point ensures that only the exact colors appear in the image an no blending between colors happens in adjacent areas. When using Eevee set the *Filter Size* in the *Film* panel to zero, for Cycles select *Box Filter*.

---

There are other options to accomplish the same task in the compositor. For instance if you'd be using Cycles, the Cryptomatte would give you masks for objects or materials.

Comment: Thanks, I will upvote you once my answer is at the top

Comment: This looks as if it might be the correct answer to [this recent question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/154163/35559) too?

Comment: @RobinBetts yes it does. The HSV value without gamma correction would be (0.0, 0.0, 0.5) and with gamma correction (0.0, 0.0, 0.735357)

Comment: I think it's reasonable to change the number of samples to 1 instead of decreasing filter size to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Special thanks to @rjg for somewhat getting me in the right direction.

The `dither` should be set to `0`:

[image]

And `View Transform` to `Standard`

[image]

Bonus picture

[image]