# How can an accurate height map be created in Blender?

Tags: shaders, height-map

We have been working to create a height map output with the shader editor. We have a plane that has been sculpted into a terrain.

[image]

We have applied a material with the following node setup to get the correct white to black shading according to height:

[image: texture coordinate, separate xyz, color ramp, output]

The middle color stop in the color ramp has its color set to HSV and the H is 0, S is 0, and V is 0.5.

The shading this applies to the object is then recorded by a camera directly above it, with all rotation axes set to 0. Under the camera tab, its lens type is set to orthographic and the scale was set up so it would frame the object correctly.

[image: shader result on object, camera settings]

However, when I import the height map this makes into Godot and set it up, there is a crease where the grayscale has changed color way too quickly, and the high points of the map are squished down.

What else needs to be adjusted here in order for this to work?

Comment: HSV is non-linear.. see for example [this recent Q&A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/154528/35559) .. make sure you're in linear space all the way through .. a Mist pass may also be an option .. P.S.. do you need a color-ramp at all?

Comment: This likely cause by using HSV. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154163/incorrect-gradient-in-linear-color-ramp/154528#154528

Comment: @RobinBetts was a bit faster. I agree with him, the mist pass would be exactly what you need. It's essentially a depth pass normalized to the [0.0-1.0] range.

Comment: You are right, getting rid of the color ramp makes no apparent difference. How do i set up a mist pass?

Comment: In Cycles View Layers tab, enable Mist Pass - then the settings are available in the World tab beneath Ambient Occlusion. Right-click dragging over a color render will give you a report about each pixel in the lower left including Z-depth. Use that info to adjust Mist distances optimally. Save a high-quality 16-bit png. Anything less also compresses grays and limits darks exaggerating brights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just looked into your way of making a height map, which seems a bit snappier than a Mist pass for something like this - I'd never thought of doing it this way...

So long as you keep the color-space linear all the way through, it works fine, as far as I can see.

[image]

In the Render > Color Management panel, set the View Transform to 'Raw'... Using EEVEE, here, but Cycles would work, too.. image saved as 16-bit RGB PNG. When used as a texture in a Displacement modifier, the Color Space in the texture must be set to 'Linear', too.

[image]

I didn't make a fuss about smoothing and subdivision, but the results seem accurate. Original on the left, displacement with EEVEE image & displacement with Cycles image on the right, with the Displacement modifier set to a Strength of the Z dimension of the original object.

Comment: Funky, why does the right geometry look so noise from above?

Comment: @Leander, thanks for that.. couldn't track the fault down or even get it to go linear for a while .. a  fresh .blend fixed it.. one of those strange ones.. all the settings seemed fine. Ironic.. it was supposed to be a quick method.... :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to cause more work. I was just interested.

Comment: @Leander No problem at all, you were absolutely right.. just wish I'd solved the mystery...

Comment: That 'Raw' part is what we were still missing after the comments under the question. Thanks.