# Setting up real displacement in 2.8

Tags: displacement

I've been struggling to get a height map to be displaced in a plane. I'm trying to do what is done so nicely in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/154900/7548), and in fact, do it with a variant of the height map in that question, which was also me.

I have now tried 2 approaches with 2 planes, both of which are in the attached file. The planes are UV unwrapped.The first approach was to add a subdivision surface modifier, and a displace modifier with the height map image as its texture.

[image: blender window showing editors for all involved settings]

The second approach was with a shader. It plugs the color data from the image texture from the height map into the Y axis of a Combine XYZ node, and then plugs that into a vector displacement node, and from there into displacement on the material output.

[image]

Neither method is working. For both planes, Displacement and Bump is selected under Properties > Materials > Settings > Surface. Cycles is the render engine. What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: have you been in the Properties panel > Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement, then choose Displacement Only or Displacement and Bump. If it still doesn't work maybe share your file?

Comment: @moonboots No, I hadn't, thanks. Also there was another problem - the strength in the displacement modifier was set to 1, so nothing was offset.

Comment: @moonboots But I continue to have problems. I'm going to edit the post and include the file.

Comment: Try to set scale of the node around 200-500 to see any displacement. As for modifier approach - use UV map instead of Local coordinates. I don't know why but there is some problem with the last one.

Comment: @SergeL I was trying to use UV coordinates, and I don't understand why it used local coordinates. Maybe that was the source of the problem in the modifier case, but I was trying to tell it to use UV coordinates, and it never occurred to me it wasn't.

Comment: Your meshes are too large, about 1km wide. If you scale them down to 10m then apply the scale you will see the displacement.

Comment: @FFeller, so maybe give this as an answer  ;)

Comment: I find out that adjusting min/max cropping in texture's settings of displace modifier bring out local and global coordinates from (-1;1) limits. But it is very unconvinient to do.

Comment: @FFeller the objects are the scale I need them to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything works fine.

[image]

[image]

But you forgot to choose a UV for modifier approach

[image]

and used a wrong setup for shader displacement.

[image]

Also you'd better re-export your height map as OpenEXR or PNG 32 bit otherwise the result shall be jagged.

[image]
[image]

Your example file on developer.blender.org works fine too.

[image]

Comment: Based on a question comment from Serge L, I had already set the Texture Coordinate field to UV, but the effect looked the same as the tiling (flat), and I didn't realize that was due to Strength needing to be adjusted way upwards. I bet I tried sliding it around, couldn't see a visible effect and discarded that. So I really needed a full answer like this one. Thanks. This should help others too as there currently aren't instructions for this out there, that I could find. PS to get a small example file I used low bit depth, but as this is for a game, we are using 16 bit PNG for the source file.